# Simultaneous continuous actions in single sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we drop second auxiliary for simultaneous continuous actions in same sentence?
Is second variant correct:

> They are walking and are talking to each other.

Or:

> They are walking and talking to each other.

Please, give me some links to read further about the rules used.

Comment: Ronald Sole's answer is good, but there may be other considerations. "They are walking and talking to each other" might suggest that they are walking to each other. The second auxiliary usefully avoids this.

Comment: Old Brixtonian, yeah same as written here (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96193/289521): "In writing, it usually produces ambiguity, and in the wrong hands, occasionally ungrammaticality; in writing one shouldn't delete words without a good reason."

Comment: It seems that this clause of Wikipedia's article about coordination gives an answer: [Gapping or not?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_%28linguistics%29#Gapping_or_not%3F)

Comment: Yes. That Wiki bit's good. (Blimey - they got a word for *everything*! *Gapping* and *stripping*?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is idiomatic to drop the second auxiliary verb in examples such as yours, especially when the two actions tally, as in **were eating and drinking**.

However, it is natural to include the second auxiliary verb when the second action is unexpected and you want to emphasise it:

> They are coming down the road and (they) **are** carrying pistols.
>   The men are buying cigarettes and (they) **are** giving them to the boys.

I am not aware of any rule concerning the inclusion or exclusion of a second auxiliary verb. In most cases it will be optional, depending on the context.

See this previous answer to the question.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157198/duplicate-auxiliary-verbs-in-a-sentence-may-we-should-we-delete-the-second